# Как правильно сделать отрисовку анимации каждого объекта в Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

Как можно сделать реализацию кода так что бы при смене статы у каждого объекта `Enemy` была своя личная анимация... вот код:

```
public class Enemy{
    enum StateEnemy {
         Walking, Deadening
    }
    private StateEnemy stateEnemy = Enemy.StateEnemy.Walking;
    public boolean isDie = false;
}
```

через `switch` выбираю то что нужно (`int num` в поле класса `Game`):

```
if(arrayEnemy.size != 0){
        switch (arrayEnemy.get(num).getStateEnemy()) {

        case Walking:
            frameEnemy = animWalkEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
            break;  
        case Deadening:
            frameEnemy = animDeadEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
            break;  
        }
    }
```

затем добираюсь к этому классу по коду (`int num` в поле класса `Game`):

```
if(arrayEnemy.get(num).isDie){
                arrayEnemy.get(num).setStateEnemy(StateEnemy.Deadening);
                    arrayEnemy.removeIndex(num);
                    break;
                }
```

Отрисовка идет в рендере таким образом (`int num` в методе `renderer`):

```
    int num = 0;
    TextureRegion frameEnemy = null;
            if(arrayEnemy.size != 0){
                switch (arrayEnemy.get(num).stateEnemy) {

                case Walking:
                    frameEnemy = animWalkEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
                    break;  
                case Deadening:
                    frameEnemy = animDeadEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
                    break;  
                }
            }

    for(num=0; num < arrayEnemy.size; num++){
                batch.draw(frameEnemy, arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().x,
                arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().y, 
                Enemy.WIDTH, Enemy.HEIGHT);
            }
```

Дело в том что если на карте в игре появляются два объекта `Enemy` то при убивании одного другому тоже присваивается стата `Deadening`. Предполагаю, что проблема кроется в самой отрисовке.

Comment: А как происходит сам процесс уничтожения врага? Т.е как именно это в коде прописано у Вас?

Comment: как обычно делаю через arrayEnemy

Comment: @SlandShow  if(arrayEnemy.get(num).isDie){arrayEnemy.removeIndex(num);}

Comment: @SlandShow проблема не в том как я это делаю... а в том что Enum статичный... поэтому вся анимация воспроизводится на все объекты... а сам Enum объявлен в классе Enemy это очевидно.

Comment: @SlandShow тобишь добераясь до этого класса я выставляю стату arrayEnemy.get(num).setStateEnemy(StateEnemy.Deadening); и она тупо применятеся для всех объектов . это не есть хорошо

Comment: Ну Вы правильно заметили, что все объекты в перечислениях статичны. Но мне, опять же, не совсем понятно то, почему эта схема не работает. Может у вас stateEnemy тоже статичный?

Comment: @SlandShow stateEnemy так и так будет статичный потому как ссылается на Enum взгляните на код внимательно и подумайте.

Comment: @SlandShow я тут пытаюсь реализовать подругому и убрать Enum так как он статичный ... вот таким образом :  public final byte WALKING = 0; public final byte DEADENING = 1;   но что то дальше ни как придумать не могу... как в switche получить все это добро и сравнивать как это ыбло в Enum arrayEnemy.get(num).getStateEnemy()

Comment: @SlandShow взгялни еще раз на код я его отредактировал может так понятнее будет?

Comment: @SlandShow чем бы вы посоветовали заменить этот статичный Enum ? он явно не подходит для более одного объекта...

Comment: Ну я бы сделал бы такой показатель как HP. Если указатель HP <= 0, то конкретному врагу из массива добавлялась бы новая анимация каким-нибудь методом setNewAnomation(String val), где вместо val указывался новый путь к текстуре. А затем бы и удалял этого врага из массива. Т.е я бы каждому врагу сделал бы поле HP, и добавил бы этот метод setNewAnimation(...)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50268/discussion-between-andrey-konstantinovich-and-slandshow).

Comment: Помогите ответом кто знает... у меня не получается реализация... все равно все объекты получают одну и ту же анимацию при гибели... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такое будет решение для множества объектов:

```
for(Enemy enemy : arrayEnemy) {
            TextureRegion frameEnemy = null;

            switch (enemy.getStateEnemy()) {

            case Walking:
                frameEnemy = animWalkEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
                break;  
            case Deadening:
                frameEnemy = animDeadEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
                break;  
            }

            Batch batch =  levelMap.getRenderer().getBatch();
            batch.begin();  

            for(num=0; num < arrayEnemy.size; num++){
                batch.draw(frameEnemy, enemy.getRect().x, enemy.getRect().y, 
                Enemy.WIDTH, Enemy.HEIGHT);
            }
            batch.end();
        }
```

Нужно было всего лишь сделать отрисовку для каждого объекта!