# Почему объекты в итерации удаляются задом наперед?

Tags: java, libgdx

Здравствуйте! В моем прошлом вопросе [Как правильно сделать отрисовку анимации каждого объекта в Libgdx?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604974/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-libgdx/605621) есть код такого вида:

```
if(arrayEnemy.get(num).isDie){
                arrayEnemy.get(num).setStateEnemy(StateEnemy.Deadening);
                    arrayEnemy.removeIndex(num);
                    break;
                }
```

Я хочу исправить его в такой:

```
        if(arrayEnemy.get(num).isDie){
            arrayEnemy.get(num).rendCountAnim++;
            arrayEnemy.get(num).setStateEnemy(Enemy.StateEnemy.Deadening);

            if (TimeUtils.millis()>(arrayEnemy.get(num).startTimeAnim+10000)) {
                arrayEnemy.removeIndex(num);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Соответственно в класс `Enemy` добавил поля:

```
    public long startTimeAnim = TimeUtils.millis();
    public int rendCountAnim = 0;
```

Тут я пытаюсь сказать программе, что после такого то времени объект удалялся. Вроде как работает, но задом наперед, то есть появляются к примеру три объекта поочередно в игре и если игрок убивает последнего появившегося объекта, то удаляется первый затем второй и третий последним! Как сделать правильную итерацию удаления? Что бы если игрок убивал не важно какого по счету появления (точнее добавления в массив) в игре объекта.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть класс Game или хотя бы ту его часть, где ваш код if(arrayEnemy.get(num).isDie){...}. И для чего нужна rendCountAnim?

Comment: добавлять не чего и так ясно же..да и мой класс Game сюда попросту не вместится!. rendCountAnim это для подсчета... типа таймера такого так сказать... когда он становится больше TimeUtils.millis() то враг удаляется из массива arrayEnemy